# What is the proper way of passing js variable to encoded route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-9

I have this script at my Blade:

```
<script>
function getComboA(selectObject) {
    var value = selectObject.value;  
    window.location.href = {!! json_encode(route('changeRequestStatusNhd', value)) !!}
}
</script>
```

Basically, the variable `value` holds the value of select option input and I need to pass this variable to the route `changeRequestStatusNhd` as its a parameter.

But the way I pass it in `route('changeRequestStatusNhd', value)` is wrong (**`Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`**)!

But I don't know what is the proper way of passing this js variable to laravel route...

So if you know, please let me know..

Thanks

Comment: You can not pass js varible value in php or laravel bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function getComboA(selectObject) {
    var value = selectObject.value;
    var route = "{{ route('changeRequestStatusNhd') }}"; // it will be rendered when page load.
    window.location.href = `${route}/${value}`
}
</script>
```

Laravel's Variables and function will rendered on page load.
So it is not possible to bind the Javascript variables on specific events.

Comment: What if `route('changeRequestStatusNhd')` requires a parameter? Wouldn't that error out when calling it without it?

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case you have to use laravel's Route URl based binding instead of named route.

Comment: @brombeer We can make that required parameter optional

Comment: This "only" appends the parameter to the url. Let's hope you never have an URL where the parameter is not at the end, like `posts/1/edit`

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways.

**way 1:**

In blade files, inside the script tag used like this

```
 var test = "{!! $test_varibale !!}";
```

**way 2:**

You can declare value in blade file like **way 1** type. then you can use the variable in the js file

Comment: That does not explain how to pass a JS variable to the (PHP) `route()` method. It's more about getting a PHP variable into JS